# ImportError at /admin/ No module named wiki, urls.py include wiki.urls fails

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm having a problem adding new apps to Django.

One line in urls.py breaks the admin, I know exactly which line, it's where I include('apps.wiki.urls')

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic.simple import redirect_to, direct_to_template
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', direct_to_template, { "template" : "welcome.html"}),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)), 
    url(r'^examples/', include('apps.examples.urls')),
    url(r'^polls/', include('apps.polls.urls')),
    url(r'^wiki/', include('apps.wiki.urls')), #Commenting out this line restores admin
)
```

The other apps still work.  If I go to my polls page, it works. The examples and accounts apps works too. The /wiki/ page returns the same ImportError as /admin/, but the Error occurs during template rendering on this line:

```
<a href="{% url wiki_article_add %}">Create new article</a>
```

Here is the wiki.urls.py file that's failing to include:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from apps.wiki.models import Article

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 
        'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_list',
        {
            'queryset': Article.published.all(),
        },
        name='wiki_article_index'),
    url(r'^article/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)$', 
        'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_detail',
        {
            'queryset': Article.objects.all(),
        },
        name='wiki_article_detail'),
    url(r'^history/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)$',
        'wiki.views.article_history',
        name='wiki_article_history'),
    url(r'^add/article$',
        'wiki.views.add_article',
        name='wiki_article_add'),
    url(r'^edit/article/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)$',
        'wiki.views.edit_article',
        name='wiki_article_edit'),
)
```

Anyone know why this module doesn't import? The wiki directory contains:

```
__init__.py
forms.py
models.py
urls.py
views.py
```

**Edit:** I've tried moving admin.autodiscover() to the bottom of urls.py, no change.
The exception occurs in django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 35, __ import __(name) and this bug is causing multiple errors in other apps. I said the other installed apps still work, but I discovered that they return errors.  My polls app (yes, the standard Django getting started polls app) will return the same error when I submit a vote. Should I post the full trace?

Here's my INSTALLED_APPS setting

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.markup',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'djcelery',
    'bootstrap_toolkit',
    'registration',
    'apps.examples',
    'apps.polls',
    'apps.wiki',
    'south',
)
```

Comment: you don't have namespace in your url(r'^wiki/', include('apps.wiki.urls')),

Comment: Thanks Catherine, I'll look at this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://codespatter.com/2009/04/10/how-to-add-locations-to-python-path-for-reusable-django-apps/

Credit to the above link for this solution.

Reusable apps that are tucked away in an "apps" directory were not being picked up as part of my python path. Add this to your settings file to fix the issue.

```
import sys

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "../apps"))
```

My settings are in their own directory, so I used "../apps" to navigate up one directory to find the apps dir

Answer (score 0):

Have You add `apps.wiki` into `settings.py` on parameter `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

and try to move the `admin.autodiscover()` line down to the very bottom of `urls.py`, so that it is the last line in that file. (based on [2079898](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079898/what-happen-when-i-add-a-django-app-to-installed-apps))

Comment: or Can You post here your `INSTALLED_APPS` parameter ?

Comment: moving `admin.autodiscover()` to the bottom of the urls.py had a bizarre result: it disabled the admin page links to app models and removed the "add" buttons.  I was baffled by that for a while until I thought to undo that change, and bam, back to normal admin.